# Post form data and query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm posting a date from a form: $startDate = $_POST['startDate'].

It's in the format (yyyy-mm-dd) just like the server side format. Now I would like to query my database using this dynamic value. My search query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE $startDate BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate";
```

I don't get results for my query. Is there anyone who can tell me where I went wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: echo your $sql variable to see if it is what you are expecting. You could also use $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE {$startDate} BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate"; (NOTE the curly braces around the variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the YYYY-MM-DD format you have to enclose the date literal in quotes:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE '$startDate' BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked just fine. What an easy fix.